# Leetcode BFS question: why does my queue have a null in it?

Tags: java, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am doing a leetcode BFS question: https://leetcode.com/problems/populating-next-right-pointers-in-each-node/description/

my solution is as below, it passes:

```
class Solution {
    public Node connect(Node root) {
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(root);
      
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            Queue<Node> childQ = new LinkedList<>();
            while(!q.isEmpty())
            {
                Node curr=q.remove();
                if(curr==null) break;
                curr.next=q.peek();
                if(curr.left!=null)
                {childQ.add(curr.left);childQ.add(curr.right);}
            }
            q=childQ;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

It passes only after I added the null check for the last-ever node in the queue.

```
if(curr==null) break;
```

But why would the curr be null? Somewhere a null is passed into the childQ in the last iteration. But I can't spot where. Can someone lend me an eye?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` is not coming from the `childQ` queue. It can only happen when `root` is `null` since the code challenge description says that the number of nodes in the tree could be 0. This means `root` is `null`.

So you *can* remove that `if` statement, but you should have one at the very start of the function to detect this corner case:

```
    public Node connect(Node root) {
        if(root==null) return root; // corner case
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(root);
      
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            Queue<Node> childQ = new LinkedList<>();
            while(!q.isEmpty())
            {
                Node curr=q.remove();
                curr.next=q.peek();
                if(curr.left!=null)
                {
                    childQ.add(curr.left);
                    childQ.add(curr.right);
                }
            }
            q=childQ;
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: You are right! The solution passes like that.  THanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you!